# write data to db in yii2

Tags: database, yii2

I have signup form which register a new user. But when i input data all fields exept one(username) saving in DB. I can't figure why. Help me.

here is my code from SignupForm

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\user\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use Yii;

/**
 * Signup form
 */
class SignupForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $verifyCode;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['username', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
            ['username', 'required'],
            ['username', 'match', 'pattern' => '#^[\w_-]+$#i'],
            ['username', 'unique', 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'],
            ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],

            ['email', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
            ['email', 'required'],
            ['email', 'email'],
            ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'message' => 'This email address has already been taken.'],

            ['password', 'required'],
            ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6],

            ['verifyCode', 'captcha', 'captchaAction' => '/user/default/captcha'],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'username' => Yii::t('app', 'USER_USERNAME'),
            'email' => Yii::t('app', 'USER_EMAIL'),
            'password' => Yii::t('app', 'USER_PASSWORD'),
            'verifyCode' => Yii::t('app', 'USER_VERIFYCODE'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Signs user up.
     *
     * @return User|null the saved model or null if saving fails
     */
    public function signup()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $user = new User();
            $user->username = $this->username;
            $user->email = $this->email;
            $user->setPassword($this->password);
            $user->status = User::STATUS_WAIT;
            $user->generateAuthKey();
            $user->generateEmailConfirmToken();

            if ($user->save()) {
                Yii::$app->mailer->compose('@app/modules/user/mails/emailConfirm', ['user' => $user])
                    ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => Yii::$app->name])
                    ->setTo($this->email)
                    ->setSubject('Email confirmation for ' . Yii::$app->name)
                    ->send();
            }

            return $user;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

code from signup(view)

```
<?php

use yii\captcha\Captcha;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $form yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm */
/* @var $model app\modules\user\models\SignupForm */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'TITLE_SIGNUP');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="user-default-signup">
    <h1><?= Yii::t('app', 'TITLE_SIGNUP') ?></h1>

    <p>Please fill out the following fields to signup:</p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-signup']); ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'username') -> textInput() ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'email') -> textInput() ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'verifyCode')->widget(Captcha::className(), [
                'captchaAction' => '/user/default/captcha',
                'template' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-3">{image}</div><div class="col-lg-6">{input}</div></div>',
            ]) ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Signup', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
            </div>
            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

code from DefaultController

```
...    
public function actionSignup()
    {
        $model = new SignupForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if ($user = $model->signup()) {
                Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', 'Подтвердите ваш электронный адрес.');
                return $this->goHome();
            }
        }

        return $this->render('signup', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
...
```

code from User(model)

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\user\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "{{%user}}".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $created_at
 * @property integer $updated_at
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $auth_key
 * @property string $email_confirm_token
 * @property string $password_hash
 * @property string $password_reset_token
 * @property string $email
 * @property integer $status
 */

class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{

    const SCENARIO_PROFILE = 'profile';

    const STATUS_BLOCKED = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;
    const STATUS_WAIT = 2;

    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $authKey;
    public $accessToken;


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['username', 'required'],
            ['username', 'match', 'pattern' => '#^[\w_-]+$#i'],
            ['username', 'unique', 'targetClass' => self::className(), 'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'],
            ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],


            ['email', 'required', 'except' => self::SCENARIO_PROFILE],
            ['email', 'email', 'except' => self::SCENARIO_PROFILE],
            ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => self::className(), 'except' => self::SCENARIO_PROFILE, 'message' => Yii::t('app', 'ERROR_EMAIL_EXISTS')],
            ['email', 'string', 'max' => 255, 'except' => self::SCENARIO_PROFILE],


            ['status', 'integer'],
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => array_keys(self::getStatusesArray())],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'created_at' => Yii::t('app', 'USER_CREATED'), //'Создан',
            'updated_at' => Yii::t('app', 'USER_UPDATE'), //'Обновлён',
            'username' => Yii::t('app', 'USER_USERNAME'), // 'Имя пользователя',
            'email' => Yii::t('app', 'USER_EMAIL'), // 'Email',
            'status' => Yii::t('app', 'USER_STATUS'), //'Статус',
        ];
    }

    public function scenarios()
    {
        return [
            self::SCENARIO_DEFAULT => ['username', 'email', 'status'],
            self::SCENARIO_PROFILE => ['email'],
        ];
    }


    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */

    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */

    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException('findIdentityByAccessToken is not implemented.');
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return static|null
     */

    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        return static::findOne(['username' => $username]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */

    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */

    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */



    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
    }

    public function getStatusName()
    {
        return ArrayHelper::getValue(self::getStatusesArray(), $this->status);
    }

    public static function getStatusesArray()
    {
        return [
            self::STATUS_BLOCKED => 'Заблокирован',
            self::STATUS_ACTIVE => 'Активен',
            self::STATUS_WAIT => 'Ожидает подтверждения',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
    }

    /**
     * Generates "remember me" authentication key
     */
    public function generateAuthKey()
    {
        $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    }

    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            if ($insert) {
                $this->generateAuthKey();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

//************************************
    /**
     * Finds user by password reset token
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByPasswordResetToken($token)
    {
        if (!static::isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)) {
            return null;
        }
        return static::findOne([
            'password_reset_token' => $token,
            'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds out if password reset token is valid
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static function isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)
    {
        if (empty($token)) {
            return false;
        }
        $expire = Yii::$app->params['user.passwordResetTokenExpire'];
        $parts = explode('_', $token);
        $timestamp = (int) end($parts);
        return $timestamp + $expire >= time();
    }

    /**
     * Generates new password reset token
     */
    public function generatePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '_' . time();
    }

    /**
     * Removes password reset token
     */
    public function removePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = null;
    }

//************************************
    /**
     * @param string $email_confirm_token
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByEmailConfirmToken($email_confirm_token)
    {
        return static::findOne(['email_confirm_token' => $email_confirm_token, 'status' => self::STATUS_WAIT]);
    }

    /**
     * Generates email confirmation token
     */
    public function generateEmailConfirmToken()
    {
        $this->email_confirm_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    }

    /**
     * Removes email confirmation token
     */
    public function removeEmailConfirmToken()
    {
        $this->email_confirm_token = null;
    }

}
```

[image: image from DB]

Comment: Did you check in your model `User` the rule(s) of username attribute?

Comment: @Clyff yes. I have add User(model) above

Comment: To find a solution, you need to constantly add `exit();` line after important line. For example, in Controller it could be `if ($user = $model->signup()) {`. Find where it fails. By the way, is other information being saved successfully?

Comment: yes all exept username. if so must be another problem

Comment: Ok, what do you see in username field in DB?

Comment: @Edvin Tenovimas nothing it's empty. But my signup form send confirm email , and when i open confirm message in yandex.ru there have username. So it have name when it sending a message but not save it in DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have got `username` attribute directly declared in `User` model here:

```
public $username;
```

Remove it so it can be mapped by ActiveRecord.

See [the note in the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#accessing-data) about this.

Comment: Good question. Seems totally without a reason. And I think your answer is correct... Take an upvote.

Comment: @Bizley thanks now it work. And thank u too  Edvin Tenovimas and @ Clyff